Google Geo chart tooltips dont work on provinces
I tried to show tooltips on Australia's map based on states/provinces, but I realised this feature is only working per country in the google document: (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#full). Currently when I mouseover or click on each state, no data is shown. Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work for states?
const options = {
    region: 'AU',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    // title: 'Group Usage Chart',
    sizeAxis: { minSize: 10 },
    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
    backgroundColor: '#81D4FA',
    datalessRegionColor: '#0059b3',
    defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    height: 700,
}

export const data = [
    [
        'State',
        'Primary usage',
        { role: 'tooltip', type: 'string', p: { html: true } },
    ],
    ['VIC', 11],
    ['NSW', 22],
    ['QLD', 2],
    ['TAS', 2],
]
.......

<Chart
   chartType="GeoChart"
   data={data}
   options={options}
   mapsApiKey={mapsApiKey}
   chartEvents={[
   {
    eventName: 'ready',
    callback: onChartReady,
    },
   ]}
/>

I tried to show tooltips on Australia's map based on states/provinces, but I realised this feature is only working per country in the google document: (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#full). Currently when I mouseover or click on each state, no data is shown. Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work for states?
